# Magento 2: header links missing from checkout pages

Tags: magento2, checkout, theme, header

In Magento 2, the "header links" element (top.links) is missing on checkout pages.  I'm using a custom theme with Magento/blank as the parent.  I have added custom links to my theme at app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml, and I want those links to also appear on checkout pages (everything after the cart page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme's xml file:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<themename>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Write this code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
      <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
      <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
      <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks, that adds the links back, but now the logo is missing?

Comment: Add this line in the xml : <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>

Comment: @Brad Try above solution this will work.

Answer (score 1):

For magento 2.2

For file checkout_index_index.xml

Change this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout"
```

To this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
```

Yes, just change attribute layout ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just copy the content of your

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

To

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

Flush cache and check.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to have any effect.